# Explicit type conversion in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am joining the two tables using the query below:

```
update campaign_items
set last_modified = evt.event_time
from (
    select max(event_time) event_time
        ,result
    from events
    where request = '/campaignitem/add'
    group by result
    ) evt
where evt.result = campaign_items.id
```

where the result column is of character varying type and the id is of integer type
But the data in the result column contains digits(i.e. 12345)

How would I run this query with converting the type of the result(character) into id
(integer)

Comment: Use the :: operator (evt.result::int = campaign_items.id)

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS

Comment: You can cast it by `CAST(evt.result as int)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you don't need to because postgresql will do implicit type conversion in this situation. For example, you can try

```
 select ' 12 ' = 12
```

You will see that it returns true even though there is extra whitespace in the string version. Nevertheless, if you need explicit conversion.

```
 where evt.result::int = campaign_items.id
```

According to your comment you have values like convRepeatDelay, these obviously cannot be converted to int. What you should then do is convert your int to char!!

```
 where evt.result = campaign_items.id::char
```

Comment: I run using your suggestion and got below error                                                      ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "convRepeatDelay"

Comment: Its working without any error,but there is no changes in database  :->Query returned successfully: 0 rows affected, 275 msec execution time.

Comment: specifically add some sample data from both tables

Comment: glad to have been of help.

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions. You can use the cast operator :: to cast a value from a given type into another type:

```
WHERE evt.result::int = campaign_items.id
```

You can also use the CAST function, which is more portable:

```
WHERE CAST(evt.result AS int) = campaign_items.id
```

Note that to improve performances, you can add an index on the casting operation (note the mandatory double parentheses), but then you have to use GROUP BY result::int instead of GROUP BY result to take advantage of the index:

```
CREATE INDEX i_events_result ON events_items ((result::int));
```

By the way the best option is maybe to change the result column type to int if you know that it will only contain integers ;-)

Comment: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "convRepeatDelay"

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise on what is going wrong? It seems the result column is from the events table and not the campaign_items table, I update this :-)

Comment: Yes you right "result" & "id" are two column from" events" & "campaign_items" table respectively.

Comment: Oh, or that means that one of you result values is "convRepeatDelay". Can you check this with "SELECT * FROM events WHERE result = 'convRepeatDelay';"?

Comment: Ohh yeah..Thats right even i am amazed..So what should i do now?

Comment: Consider the solution of e4c5 ;-)